# How to send named JSON objects from Web API 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Currently my Web API sends JSON data as an UNNAMED array of objects like this:

```
[
  {
    "productTypeId": 1,
    "productCategoryId": 4,
    "name": "Provider Frame",
    "memberCost": 75.00,
    "providerCost": 25.00
  },
  {
    "productTypeId": 1,
    "productCategoryId": 4,
    "name": "Customer Frame",
    "memberCost": 0.00,
    "providerCost": 0.00
  },
  {
    "productTypeId": 1,
    "productCategoryId": 4,
    "name": "Fireproof Frame",
    "memberCost": 75.00,
    "providerCost": 25.00
  }
]
```

Is there a way to change the API to send data like this?

```
{
  "frames": [
  {
    "productTypeId": 1,
    "productCategoryId": 4,
    "name": "Provider Frame",
    "memberCost": 75.00,
    "providerCost": 25.00
  },
  {
    "productTypeId": 1,
    "productCategoryId": 4,
    "name": "Customer Frame",
    "memberCost": 0.00,
    "providerCost": 0.00
  },
  {
    "productTypeId": 1,
    "productCategoryId": 4,
    "name": "Fireproof Frame",
    "memberCost": 75.00,
    "providerCost": 25.00
  }
 ]
}
```

I want to give my front-end framework the ability to read the JSON object by name instead of assuming it's "data". Does this make sense?

Here is the code for the Web API:

```
public sealed class FramesController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IProductService prodSvc;
        public FramesController(IProductService _prodSvc)
        {
            prodSvc = _prodSvc;
        }


        public IEnumerable<Product> GetFrames(int productTypeId)
        {
            return prodSvc.GetProductsByCategoryId((int)Enums.CategoryGroup.Frame, productTypeId);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the action to return the data encapsulated in an object with the desired property name

```
public sealed class FramesController : ApiController {
    private readonly IProductService prodSvc;

    public FramesController(IProductService _prodSvc) {
        prodSvc = _prodSvc;
    }


    public IHttpActionResult GetFrames(int productTypeId) {
        var products = prodSvc.GetProductsByCategoryId((int)Enums.CategoryGroup.Frame, productTypeId);

        if(!products.Any())
            return NotFound();

        var result = new { frames = products.ToArray() };
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

The above example uses an anonymous type but could just as easily used a concrete type like

```
public class GetFramesResult {
    public Product[] frames { get; set; }
}
```

and used in the action

```
var result = new GetFramesResult { frames = products.ToArray() };
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your response type with a class and give it an array property named "frames" which has type of frame class.

Take some help from http://json2csharp.com/

You should return instance of YourResponse class as shown below :

```
public class Frame
{
    public int productTypeId { get; set; }
    public int productCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public double memberCost { get; set; }
    public double providerCost { get; set; }
}

public class YourResponse
{
    public List<Frame> frames { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExpandoObject:

```
dynamic data = new ExpandoObject();
data.frames = yourObject;
return Json(data);
```

Comment: There's no need for the ExpandoObject here, simply using `Json(new { frames = yourObject })` is enough